# Invalid Signature Key IdentityServer4

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I'm facing this exception in my authenticated applications with identityserver4:

> SecurityTokenInvalidSignatureException: IDX10503: Signature validation failed. Keys tried: 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.RsaSecurityKey , KeyId: 
>    '. Exceptions caught: ''. token: '{"alg":"RS256","typ":"JWT"}.{"nbf":1501510053,"exp":1501510353,"iss":"http://localhost:5000","aud":"clientId","nonce":"636371068531446271.Nzc2YzRjZGMtN2M0Ny00MGZiLWI3NTQtN2Q2NWIxZGM5MWUyODY2MGE5NTgtYWMzNS00YWJmLWEyMDktNjcwMmJhYTlkYWJk","iat":1501510053,"c_hash":"teGUAAIvU0EY9L1WzjfI2Q","sid":"c870b6184744290472b157ce5992f8e0","sub":"a3915666-8586-476b-9166-b5b183af609e","auth_time":1501508734,"idp":"local","amr":["pwd"]}'.

At this time, I don't have a certificate to use in my Sign in credentials in identity server. So I try this code, sometimes works, but I have sure this is wrong. Someone have a step by step how to use SignInCredentials without a .pfx certificate?

```
var signinkey = new RsaSecurityKey(RSA.Create());

        var signingCredentials = new SigningCredentials(signinkey,
            SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSha256);

        // Adds IdentityServer
        services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddSigningCredential(signingCredentials)
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

`services.AddIdentityServer().AddDeveloperSigningCredential()`

This will create you a random RSA key pair at first launch and cache it on disk.

Comment: Ok, but if my application restarts, my tokens won't invalidate?

Comment: No - the key will be re-used until you delete the key file.

Comment: yes - https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/dev/src/IdentityServer4/Configuration/DependencyInjection/BuilderExtensions/Crypto.cs#L108